# CodenameOne icons of buttons get lost on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have a very weird iOS problem:

Buttons (or tabs) with icons loose their icon over time.
I.e.

```
...
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("native:MainLight", "native:MainLight").
         derive(Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(5, true), Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
Style s = new Style(button.getStyle().getFgColor(), 0, fnt, (byte) 0);

button.setIcon((FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MAP, s)
                .toImage().scaled(iconSize, iconSize)));
...
```

would work at first, later (after some time) it would loose its icon.

Restarts of the app wont help, The only way to solve this is to **totally remove the app and to reinstall it** - however after some time the problem appears again.

Comment: Since we don't store icon information anywhere this has to be some code on your side that relies on storage. Can you reproduce this in the simulator? Are there additional places that invoke these methods?

Comment: I have this problem also with tabs `tabs.addTab("Mail", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MAIL_OUTLINE ...`. In this case some of the tabs loose their icon randomly. It just affects FontImage materials and just on the iPhone, I can't reproduce it anywhere else. 
Anyway, this app is quite memory demanding, so I'm not sure if iOS just drops randomly graphics, but the problem persists even after a restart of the entire phone or an update of the app - the same FontImage icons are missing and never return. I don't know about the persistence on iOS, maybe this could be the reason?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a standalone test case?

Comment: I could not fix it and have no time to create a standalone test case at the moment. However the workaround I used was to simply replace the FontImages with icons stored in the resource file.